# orchestral/tenanti Driver not supported error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

I am trying to use the [orchestral/tenanti](https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti) package in my laravel 5 installation to get a multi database multi tenant architecture up and running but I am not sure how to proceed after the installation.

I have followed the installation instructions carefully and installed the package through composer, defined the service providers and the alias in the `config/app.php` file and I also went ahead ahead and edited the AppServiceProvider's boot method.

Now [this section](https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti#observer) in the documentation is blurry to me. What is it supposed to mean?

And after that, how am I supposed to proceed from here on?
When I try the new artisan commands that come with the package like `tenanti:install` and others like it I keep getting an error `Driver [mysql] not supported` and so on. What am I doing wrong and how to set up this package correctly and where to go after the package has been set up.

Where do I create the migration files for the main DB and where do I create the migration files for the tenant DB? And how do I use this package inside my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver here describe the unique identifier for your tenant, tenant could be based on company, team, site etc. You might even have multiple drivers in a single application.

So in order to describe a driver, you must decide how you want to structure your application, let say you decide that user can have multiple sites, and each site has it's own tenant database.

```
'drivers' => [
    'site' => [
        'model' => App\Site::class, \\ The eloquent model for `sites` table.
        'migration' => 'tenant_migrations',
        'path' => database_path('tenanti/site'),
    ]
],
```

Now assume that you have created the `App\Site` model, and create the observer as describe in the readme.

You can create new migration schema by using `php artisan tenanti:make site create_posts_table`. This command would now create a new migration schema in `database/tenant/site/`.

Once you have the migration, create a record through Eloquent, or manually and run `php artisan tenanti:migrate site`.

#### Problem with Multi-Database Tenant

It easy to make your database connection to swap between the default and current tenant (using migration etc), however when we want to run the migration from a command line, it not possible to dynamically swap between connection as we don't know this information (console doesn't use middleware).

To solve this, you need to setup [Database Connection Resolver](https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti#database-connection-resolver)